# Swift - How to reset tagged images on e.g. "game board"?

Tags: swift, xcode

I've been trying to reset the tagged images on a Tic Tac Toe board game and cannot work out how to change the individual "squares" once they are set. I've done searches and I can't seem to find anything about it.

I use one action button for the whole board with 9 tagged image squares (one in each square). They are all linked to the same IBAction. When I press a square I get alternate cross or nought image displaying. I want to then have a separate action button where I can reset the board and play again. How do i revert back the squares to their original states (i.e. showing nothing)?

```
let nought = UIImage(named: "nought.png") as UIImage!
let cross = UIImage(named: "cross") as UIImage!
var noughtArray = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
var crossArray = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
var whichPlayer = true

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }

    if !crossArray[button.tag] && !noughtArray[button.tag] {

        if whichPlayer {

            button.setImage(nought, for: .normal)

            print("Button \(button.tag + 1) pressed!")

            noughtArray[button.tag] = true

            if winningCombination(array: noughtArray) {

                labelWinner.text = "Winner is Noughts!"

                animateWinning()

            }

            whichPlayer = false

        } else {

            button.setImage(cross, for: .normal)

            print("Button \(button.tag + 1) pressed!")

            crossArray[button.tag] = true

            if winningCombination(array: crossArray) {

                labelWinner.text = "Winner is Crosses!"

                animateWinning()

            }

            whichPlayer = true

        }

    }

}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access all of your buttons in your `reset` function.  To do this, you need to create an `@IBOutlet` collection:

1. Create an `@IBOutlet` collection to hold references to your buttons:

   ```
   @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
   ```
2. Connect all of your buttons to this `@IBOutlet` collection in the *Storyboard* by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from each button in turn to the line of code in step 1.
3. In your reset function, loop over all of the buttons and set their image to `nil`:

   ```
   @IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton) {
       for button in buttons {
           button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
       }

       // Reset other variables to starting conditions
       naughtArray = Array(repeating: false, count: 9)
       crossArray  = naughtArray
       whichPlayer = true
   }
   ```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! So you're basically doing the same thing again as the main function but with a loop. Makes total sense... now :)

Comment: Yep.  BTW, if you change to `@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton)` you can eliminate the `guard` statement.

Comment: huh...did not know that. Makes it much cleaner. Again, thanks! Really appreciated!