# How do I get my tic tac toe board to reset? When I reset after a draw or win the boxes don't reset

Tags: ios, swift

When I reset after a win or draw the letters of X and O stay. The color just fades (.alpha) and when you press the square again it just changes the letter. I need the tic tac toe to reset. I know the code works because I got it from GitHub and watched the YouTube video. I did it over and over again to the 5th time. I just copied the code that needed to be copied and it still doesn't work. His code works.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    enum Turn {
        case Nought
        case Cross
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var turnLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var a1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var a2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var a3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c3: UIButton!
    
    var firstTurn = Turn.Cross
    var currentTurn = Turn.Cross
    
    var NOUGHT = "O"
    var CROSS = "X"
    var board = [UIButton]()
    
    var noughtsScore = 0
    var crossesScore = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initBoard()
    }
    
    func initBoard()
    {
        board.append(a1)
        board.append(a2)
        board.append(a3)
        board.append(b1)
        board.append(b2)
        board.append(b3)
        board.append(c1)
        board.append(c2)
        board.append(c3)
    }

    @IBAction func boardTapAction(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        addToBoard(sender)
        
        if checkForVictory(CROSS)
        {
            crossesScore += 1
            resultAlert(title: "Crosses Win!")
        }
        
        if checkForVictory(NOUGHT)
        {
            noughtsScore += 1
            resultAlert(title: "Noughts Win!")
        }
        
        if(fullBoard())
        {
            resultAlert(title: "Draw")
        }
    }
    
    func checkForVictory(_ s :String) -> Bool
    {
        // Horizontal Victory
        if thisSymbol(a1, s) && thisSymbol(a2, s) && thisSymbol(a3, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        if thisSymbol(b1, s) && thisSymbol(b2, s) && thisSymbol(b3, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        if thisSymbol(c1, s) && thisSymbol(c2, s) && thisSymbol(c3, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        
        // Vertical Victory
        if thisSymbol(a1, s) && thisSymbol(b1, s) && thisSymbol(c1, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        if thisSymbol(a2, s) && thisSymbol(b2, s) && thisSymbol(c2, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        if thisSymbol(a3, s) && thisSymbol(b3, s) && thisSymbol(c3, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        
        // Diagonal Victory
        if thisSymbol(a1, s) && thisSymbol(b2, s) && thisSymbol(c3, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        if thisSymbol(a3, s) && thisSymbol(b2, s) && thisSymbol(c1, s)
        {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
    
    func thisSymbol(_ button: UIButton, _ symbol: String) -> Bool
    {
        return button.title(for: .normal) == symbol
    }
    
    func resultAlert(title: String)
    {
        let message = "\nO's " + String(noughtsScore) + "\n\nX's " + String(crossesScore)
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            self.resetBoard()
        }))
        self.present(ac, animated: true)
    }
    
    func resetBoard()
    {
        for button in board
        {
            button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
            button.isEnabled = true
        }
        if firstTurn == Turn.Nought
        {
            firstTurn = Turn.Cross
            turnLabel.text = CROSS
        }
        else if firstTurn == Turn.Cross
        {
            firstTurn = Turn.Nought
            turnLabel.text = NOUGHT
        }
        currentTurn = firstTurn
    }
    
    func fullBoard() -> Bool
    {
        for button in board
        {
            if button.title(for: .normal) == nil
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func addToBoard(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if(sender.title(for: .normal) == nil)
        {
            if(currentTurn == Turn.Nought)
            {
                sender.setTitle(NOUGHT, for: .normal)
                currentTurn = Turn.Cross
                turnLabel.text = CROSS
            }
            else if(currentTurn == Turn.Cross)
            {
                sender.setTitle(CROSS, for: .normal)
                currentTurn = Turn.Nought
                turnLabel.text = NOUGHT
            }
            sender.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591030/swift-how-to-reset-tagged-images-on-e-g-game-board?rq=1 , it will Help you

Comment: Is the `resetBoard` function being called ? Might be useful to share the link of the github repo / video you watched so we could assess the whole code base.